# Schedule task to take backup of Remotely hosted database on my Local System

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks, sql-server-2012-express

As I have already seen so many post but did not fine any proper solution I am posting this again.

I have one remotely hosted database. And I want to take daily backup of that on my local system. How can I do it? How can I create schedule task for the same process so I do not need to do it manually everyday?

Any Help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this:

1. Create a network share on your "local" system, enable the service account of your SQL Server instance to write on this share
2. Create a maintenenace plan on your SQL Server and have it write to the shared folder or you can create an SQL Server Agent job directly